# How do I edit repository txt with python

Tags: python

So I am working on a python project for school and I wanted to save some variables to a raw txt. If there is a way to do it by only importing requests that would be great as the program I am using does not import git.

Thanks
-Amir Ahmed

Comment: so the txt should look like

Comment: a=0
b=20
g=200000

Comment: You don't need `requests` or `git` to read a text file. You seem to have some misunderstanding about very basic things. Stack Overflow isn't a good place to come for basic questions -- you should talk to your teacher and try to find tutorials on the internet. Stack Overflow is to help you fix _specific_ problems with your algorithms / code. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and provide a [mre]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

First off, reading/writing from/to files is included in the Python Standard Library. Requests is a HTTPRequests library. The way to write to a text file is like so:

```
writer = open("path_or_relative_path.txt", "a")
writer.write("testdatatowrite\n")
writer.close()
```

This is the most basic way of writing to a text file.